# How to make .gitignore ignore compiled files with no extension?

Tags: git, gitignore

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [gitignore without binary files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5711120/gitignore-without-binary-files)

Edit: Dupe of [gitignore without binary files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5711120/gitignore-without-binary-files)

When you compile, say, a Haskell file, (`test.hs`), using `ghc --make test.hs`, the result is `test.hi` and `test`.  I only want to add and commit the source `test.hs`, while keeping `test.hi` and `test` out of the repository but in the same directory as the source file.  `test` is the problem, how do I specify to .gitignore to ignore a compiled file with no extension?

Comment: `echo "*.a" >> .gitignore` and compile with `ghc --osuf a --make test.hs`

Comment: Thanks @Eric Wilson, I searched first but didn't see that one.

Comment: @KingCrunch, heh, yes but I prefer the lazy 'git add .' when possible.

Comment: git add -A adds all changes. git add . is not enough.

Comment: this is actually not a duplicate.

Answer (score 5):

Just add the filename to your `.gitignore` file.  For example:

```
$ git ls-files --other --exclude-standard
test
$ echo test > .gitignore
$ git ls-files --other --exclude-standard
$
```

`.gitignore` doesn't care about extensions.  It just matches patterns.

Comment: Thanks, considered that but I'm at the start of the project that will have lots of these filenames.  Will resort to that if there's no better option.  PS - didn't know about ls-files command, though when I run it it still includes .hs and .txt files in the output.  Will check out the man page and play with it a bit.

Comment: I just used `ls-files` because the output is less verbose, which is nice for this particular example.  If you can't identify the files by name or by pattern you're pretty much out of luck. If you can put all your output files in a particular directory you could ignore the directory, or you could programatically generate your `.gitignore` file as part of your build process.

Comment: I think that will also ignore any directory path that has 'test' in it...