# Ignore tracking typeless files in Git

Tags: git, gitignore

I use an HDL simulator which creates lots of large (hundred MB) binaries with seemingly random names -- these files do not have an extension.  I'd like to keep these out of my Git repo.

I read on [.gitignore without binary files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5711120/gitignore-without-binary-files) a few techniques for ignoring files without extensions, but they're all pretty narrow in scope.

One of the challenges I face is that every time I run the simulator it generates new and randomly named binary outputs (e.g. it's unrealistic to manually add each one of these files to the ignore file).

Comment: Could you put all these files in their own directory and `gitignore` the directory itself?

Comment: I thought about that -- the short answer is yes, but that would be a pain and would screw up the simulator.  The simulator creates the files during use and needs them in the code directory.  If I move them I'll screw up the simulator.  Additionally it's kind of an annoying step to manually move each time I want to commit code.

Comment: I saw the suggestion to add the following lines: 
*
!*.c
on one post.  Presumably I'd put in every file type I do want where the .c is.  I guess that's an option, but not particularly robust.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can set up a pre-commit hook to check file size before committing (assuming these binaries have some kind of base file size). Something like [this](https://gist.github.com/LukasKnuth/1839424) would probably work, though I'm sure you'll want to play around with the `max_file_size` variable.

Comment: That's an interesting suggestion.  I'm hesitant to do that for a few reasons.  The first is that I have other files I do want in the repo that are of similar size to the files I don't want.  The second is that I'd really rather keep the simulator output separate from my code.  If worst comes to worst I'll try this, but I guess I'd rather avoid it if possible.

Comment: One thought to get around that is to set the hook up to ask "Y/n?" instead of failing immediately. Honestly, it might be better to just `git add` your files manually so that you're aware of exactly what's being committed.