# Github sharing process failed

Tags: android-studio, github

Before answering my question please take into consideration that I'm new to Github and how it works. I'm having trouble sharing my project to Github. I'm receiving the errors:
 The remote end hung up unexpectedly RPC failed; result=18, HTTP code = 200 
The sharing process takes very long and it stops with this error. The project gets created on Github with no code. Other forums relating to this talk about GitBash. Note this is done through android studio.

Comment: What git tool are you using ? Command line? Eclipse? Are you in a company/ school behind a proxy?

Comment: Did you already create a repository at GitHub? Can you post the url you try to clone?

Comment: It created the repository, but didn't transfer any files/code to the repository because the sharing process failed. I get the same error when trying to commit a push from android studio. Please again take in consideration that I'm a beginner at this.

Comment: The fact this error is done though android studio does not change my answer: you would get the same error with a `git push` in command line.

Comment: I don't know what any of these terms mean, you're going to have to walk me through this. I would very much appreciate it if you took your time to teach me these terms.

Answer (score 0):

As [mentioned here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=301663284)

> Specifically, the 'result=18' portion. This is the error code coming from libcurl, the underlying library used in http communications with Git. From the libcurl documentation, a result code of 18 means:

```
CURLE_PARTIAL_FILE (18)
```

> A file transfer was shorter or larger than expected. This happens when the server first reports an expected transfer size, and then delivers data that doesn't match the previously given size.

You could try and increase the http buffer:

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000
```

But first, make sure your local repo didn't include large binaries.
To be sure, [check your `.gitignore`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5711120/6309)