# How to gitignore Go binaries?

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a `.gitignore` file like this:

```
# no binaries
*/
!*.go/
!.gitignore
```

I thought `*/` means to ignore all files in all subdirectories (so every file), `!*.go/` means to not-ignore all `*.go` files in all subdirectories, and `!.gitignore` means to not ignore `.gitignore`.

However, the issue I have now is that when I create a new `*.go` file in a subdirectory, it's now ignored.

How do I correctly gitignore all compiled binaries, but not ignore `*.go` files?

I now have

```
**/*  
!**/*.go
!.gitignore
```

But it still ignores all *.go files in the ch1 directory. Anyone else have ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use:

```
**/*.go
```

The `**` is for ignoring files inside any folder and not only in the current folder.

---

#### A minor bug was fixed in git v2.7:

> Allow a later `!/abc/def` to override an earlier `/abc` that
> appears in the same `.gitignore` file to make it easier to express
> ***`everything in /abc directory is ignored, except for ...`***.

---

#### From the `.gitignore` documentation:

> **Two consecutive asterisks (`**`)** in patterns matched against full pathname may have special meaning:

### ***`Leading **`***

> **`A leading **`** followed by a `slash` means match in **all directories**.
> For example, `**/foo` matches file or directory `foo` **anywhere**, the same as pattern `foo`.
> `**/foo/bar` matches file or directory "bar" anywhere that is directly under directory `foo`.

### ***`Trailing **`***

> `A trailing /**` matches everything **inside**.
> For example, `abc/**` matches **all files inside** directory `abc`, relative to the location of the `.gitignore` file, with infinite depth.

### ***`/**/`***

> A slash followed by **two consecutive asterisks** then a slash matches zero or more directories.
> For example, `a/**/b` matches `a/b`, `a/x/b`, `a/x/y/b` and so on.

Comment: I substituted `!*.go` with `!**.*.go` but my new *.go files are till ignored

Comment: Read the updated content i added based upon this comment

Comment: I read it, and tried to apply it to no avail. I want to *not* ignore *.go source files, but ignore their binaries (which have no extension) - any more tips?

Comment: If the file has no extension it will be hard to exclude it unless you place them all in a certain folder

Answer (score 11):

This will ignore everything except .go files, and works for subdirectories too:

```
**/*
!**/*.go
!**/
```

You may also want to check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5711120), which is asking something very similar.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the Golang compiler will name your binary after the folder name containing your .go source files. In your IDE you can specify the golang compile command with build opts. In my case I have specified my IDE to run the following when I compile my .go source files on OSX:

```sh
"env GOOS=darwin GOARCH=amd64 go build -v -o bin/$(basename $(pwd)) && go test -v && go vet"
```

Notice that in my `go build` I specify the binary output path with `-o` and tell the compiler to write all binaries to the subfolder `bin/` in the current directory and to name the binary with the name of the project folder. Then in your `.gitignore` file located in your project folder, add `bin/*` and git will ignore all the files in your `bin/` subfolder.