# Gitignore on executable

Tags: regex, git, gitignore

What would be the format for excluding files that do not have an extension, such as `runme`, which does not have an extension. For example, if the files in my directory are:

```
script.sh
script.s
runme
```

I want to exclude the files without an extension. I suppose the regex for this would be [`^[^.]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/V1bzWn/1). How does this go into a `.gitignore` though? What are the regex (or is it more unix/shell filepath matching patterns)?

Comment: Please refer to this Q/A: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5711120/gitignore-without-binary-files/25592735

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`gitignore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) file format doesn't support regular expressions, just regular Unix-style [patterns](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format).

In your case, I would exclude everything and then allow the files that *do have* an extension. For example:

```
# Ignore everything
*
# Allow directories
!*/
# Allow files with an extension
!*.*
```

This would include files like these:

```
foo.txt
some/dir/bar.txt
```

But exclude files like these:

```
foo
some/dir/bar
```