# Git not ignoring the files without extension

Tags: linux, git, gitignore

I am trying to maintain my c++ program files by pushing them to GitHub. So I only push the files with the extension CPP, so that I don't include the binaries as well.

Here are my gitignore file contents

```
# Ignore all
*

# Unignore all with extensions
!*.*

# Unignore all dirs
!*/

### Above combination will ignore all files without extension ###
.vscode/
```

which I got to know from here
[gitignore binary files that have no extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5711120/gitignore-binary-files-that-have-no-extension)

which has been working fine for a long time. I am using so Linux the binaries are created with no extension. But now it doesn't ignore the binaries.

[image]

[image]

Comment: has been working, now it's not . . . what changed? If you're on linux say `file .gitignore` to see its encoding, it should be utf-8 or ascii.

Comment: What version of Git are you using?  2.34.0 has a regression that might affect this.

Comment: @jthill I ran the command you mentioned I got the result `.gitignore: ASCII text`. Even I have no idea what changed it, I guess it might be the update.

Comment: @bk2204 I am using `git version 2.34.0`

Comment: That's it, just tested, that's bugged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there's a bug in `.gitignore` handling in the just-released Git 2.34.0.  The patch (2.34.1) should be out any day now.